# What is the proper way to scale sprites in Cocos2D with Box2D?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am using PhysicsSprite class

I have changed this piece of code:

```
transform_ = CGAffineTransformMake( c,  s,
                                   -s,  c,
                                   x,   y );
```

in `nodeToParentTransform` method to:

```
transform_ = CGAffineTransformMake( c * scaleX_,  s * scaleX_,
                                   -s * scaleY_,  c * scaleY_,
                                   x,   y );
```

The problem is that physic bodies are misplaced, as you can see on this screenshot (with e_shapeBit enabled in debug drawing):

[image: square zombies]

Bodies are created as following:

```
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(brick.sprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO, brick.sprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = brick.sprite;
    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    body->SetGravityScale(0);
    brick.sprite.userData = body;

    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(levelObj.brickScale * .5f, levelObj.brickScale * .5f);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    body->SetType(b2_dynamicBody);
    brick.sprite.userObject = brick;
    [brick.sprite setPhysicsBody:body];
```

**edit:**
Sorry, I haven't made it clear enough: by scaling I mean natural Cocos2D construction `brick.sprite.scale = 0.5f`, where `brick.sprite` is instance of `PhysicsSprite` class. Without modifying `nodeToParentTransform` it gives no effect at all. Brick sprite is 32x32px, with `PTM_RATIO = 32` it gives 1x1m physical size, hence the SetBox parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to modify the *nodeToParentTransform* method to support scaling. You can initialize the shape of your body to match the dimensions of your sprite instead:

```
dynamicBox.SetAsBox(brick.sprite.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO * brick.sprite.scaleX * .5f, brick.sprite.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO * brick.sprite.scaleY * .5f);
```

Comment: Without modifying `nodeToParentTransform` `PhysicsSprite` simple ignores setting the scale. Your code is correct for setting body dimensions for scale = 1. It is wrong, however for any other scale since `contentSize` is not affected by it.

Comment: Multiply the original box size (in meters, if not, just don't multiply with PTM_RATIO) by self.scale: dynamicBox.SetAsBox(brickOriginalWidth * PTM_RATIO * self.scale, brickOriginalHeight * PTM_RATIO * self.scale);
You need to store the original box dimensions yourself somehow, somewhere.

Comment: @PeterProkop sorry, I left out the multiplication of the scale (as LearnCocos2D as pointed out). So now if you change the scale of the sprite, the created body should scale accordingly to match the new size.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is create body with the help of sprite height and weight.